# After installation Delphi 2010 can not find component's dcu files which are used in the project?

Tags: delphi, components, dcu

I finished a project years ago. Now i want to improve it. Thus i install the components which were used before in the project. But when i run the project it gives an error. compiler can not find dcu files of some component objects. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Please add more detail. There could be hundreds of explanations for whatever your problem is.

Comment: Did you add the path to (each) component's dcus to the `Tools -> Options -> Library win32 -> Library path`?

Comment: i compiled and installed component's packages. @ain i m trying now. i will post back in 5 mins.

Answer (score 5):

Just compiling and installing the package into IDE doesn't update the library path which is used by the compiler to find the `dcu-s`. You can update the Delphi 2010 library path via `Tools -> Options -> Library win32 -> Library path`.